# Docker Volume not mounting any files

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to mount my source files to a directory in docker located at /var/dynamo. I'd like to be able to run Docker locally and use my local files as I am working.

with the run command:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/var/dynamo -d -t -p 8001:8001 --name dynamo davesrepo/dynamo
```

with my  **Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.5.1
WORKDIR /var/dynamo
RUN pip3 install tornado
EXPOSE 8001
```

However, when I bash into the container `docker exec -it dynamo /bin/bash` and run `ls -la` the directory **is empty!**

```
root@7d3d338891aa:/var/dynamo# ls -la
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 Dec 29 03:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Dec 29 03:36 ..
```

Running `docker inspect dynamo` shows the directory mounted properly

```
[
{
    "Id": "7d3d338891aae32e001a3bb31d6be17802d238526830396472b011599a97212a",
    "Created": "2015-12-29T03:37:01.416445958Z",
    "Path": "python3",
    "Args": [],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 1314,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2015-12-29T03:37:01.516253705Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "19697c9b5c7561b113d817821280971f063ea0187c82343c0832348fb6863c9a",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/7d3d338891aae32e001a3bb31d6be17802d238526830396472b011599a97212a/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/7d3d338891aae32e001a3bb31d6be17802d238526830396472b011599a97212a/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/7d3d338891aae32e001a3bb31d6be17802d238526830396472b011599a97212a/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/7d3d338891aae32e001a3bb31d6be17802d238526830396472b011599a97212a/7d3d338891aae32e001a3bb31d6be17802d238526830396472b011599a97212a-json.log",
    "Name": "/dynamo",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "aufs",
    "ExecDriver": "native-0.2",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/Users/dave/Sites/davesrepo/dynamo:/var/dynamo"
        ],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LxcConf": [],
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "MemorySwappiness": -1,
        "Privileged": false,
        "PortBindings": {
            "8001/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8001"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Links": null,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "Devices": [],
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "IpcMode": "",
        "PidMode": "",
        "UTSMode": "",
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "VolumeDriver": ""
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Name": "aufs",
        "Data": null
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Source": "/Users/dave/Sites/davesrepo/dynamo",
            "Destination": "/var/dynamo",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "7d3d338891aa",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "8001/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": true,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "APP_ENV=development",
            "PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/var/dynamo",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "LANG=C.UTF-8",
            "PYTHON_VERSION=3.5.1",
            "PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=7.1.2"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "python3"
        ],
        "Image": "davesrepo/dynamo",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "/var/dynamo",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {},
        "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "71d99a7d11908a9d1c0156fd33eb3f0ff5ef9f6697bb77103fe2caa1cf488530",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "8001/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8001"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/71d99a7d1190",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "1cc99b0de89700368f31b43248c90ea45cec756712a2bd2ba2dc57293a5d0a72",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "EndpointID": "1cc99b0de89700368f31b43248c90ea45cec756712a2bd2ba2dc57293a5d0a72",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

Docker version is 1.9.1

Comment: Or what do you want to get? Did you put something in `/var/dynamo` and they're gone?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to put my files in /var/dynamo and they never showed up

Comment: Would https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17470 help?

Comment: That ticket is still open, no proposed solution in it fixes my issue.

Comment: I have found a fix for this without downgrading.

Comment: @digitaldavenyc mind sharing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Docker & Virtualbox seem to have an issue with mounting a volume outside of the /Users directory. The only way to fix the issue is to delete the docker machine image, properly set the /Users/yourname directory as the share folder in Virtualbox and create a new docker machine image.

Steps to fix the issue:

1. `docker-machine stop dev`
2. `docker-machine rm dev`
3. `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev`
4. `eval "$(docker-machine env dev)"`
5. `docker build -t davesrepo/dynamo -f ./Dockerfile .`
6. `docker run -v $(pwd):/var/dynamo -d -t -p 8001:8001 --env-file ./dynamo.env --name dynamo davesrepo/dynamo`
7. `docker exec -it dynamo /bin/bash`
8. `ls`

`root@42f9e47fa2de:/var/dynamo# ls`
`Dockerfile  README.md  __init__.py  __pycache__  bin  config.ini  requirements.txt  seed.sql  tests`

**Files!**

Comment: I am sure you hit on the cause of the problem: a folder sharing limitation in Virtualbox is the root cause.  But what is different with the way the machine is created here vs. how you created it when the sharing did not work?  How do you 'properly set the /Users/yourname directory as the share folder'?  Or how do you _not_ properly set the share folder?

Comment: When I originally setup Docker, I placed my files in /var/dynamo. This is obviously outside of the OSX User directory, this is what Virtualbox defaults to as far as I know. You properly set the files by opening Virtualbox, clicking 'settings' for your docker VM and selecting 'share folders'. From there you can double click on the machine folders and change the path. It's pretty straight forward stuff.

Comment: Finally resolved a mystery related to this and I think it's worth recording here. In addition to VirtualBox and some mentioned 'boot2docker', some other build of docker also has this limit of restricting to $HOME. I installed docker with 'snap' and found out, after lots of time spent and frustration, by executing 'snap info docker', and found the limit right there in the description.

Is it able to find out if this limit is in place by a command?

Answer (score 18):

I dont know if this is helpful to anyone but it took me about an hour trying to figure out why the mounted directories were empty since I was not getting any error messages and I could see the mounted directories within my container but without any files.

Short answer: the host directory path has to start from /home

So in my docker-compose I was WRONGLY specifying the following:

```yaml
    services:
        myservice:
            build: .
            ports:
                - 8888:8888
            volumes:
              - /Desktop/subfolder/subfolder2:/app/subfolder
```

When the host path should have been full path from /home. something like:

```yaml
    services:
        myservice:
            build: .
            ports:
                - 8888:8888
            volumes:
              - home/myuser/Desktop/subfolder/subfolder2:/app/subfolder
```

Comment: Very helpful, I still don't understand why it is not working with a relative path.

Comment: I don't know why, but using an absolute path starting with `/home` worked for me while a path starting with `${pwd}` failed (though it resolves to home). Thanks!

Comment: I spent more than 10 hours working on that. Your post saved me the next ten hours.

Comment: Thank you. For three days I have been trying to solve this problem and in the end, it was solved through your answer

Answer (score 8):

I found out that I changed my windows password and docker requires windows credentials to mount volumes, you can update it settings > shared drives.

Comment: thanks that was very helpful. In the current version of docker (2.0.0.3) in windows 10, I went to `settings > shared drives` and had to select the drive, then hit **Reset credentials**, select the drive again and hit the **Apply** button and finally was able to enter the new credentials.

Answer (score 7):

Check you `docker context` :) I forgot to change it back.

```
$ docker context use default
```

Comment: what does this do? how can i check what is the current one?

Comment: my environment is windows 10 WSL ubuntu, i had to install docker desktop on windows, docker engine, docker-compose in ubuntu, using the steps described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61902994/4582240

Answer (score 4):

## Wrong source for volume

Nothing else helped and this was rather easy;

If you run `docker inspect [containername]`, checking the "Mounts" section and the `source` on your volume is not correctly set, looking like the following: ***(Example for mongodb)***

```json
 "Mounts": [
  {
    "Type": "volume",
    "Name": "b1cdd07ca4d5621eda77481824e5068194023f4407ed2674ec81a1573f2d0410",
    "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/b1cdd07ca4d5621eda77481824e5068194023f4407ed2674ec81a1573f2d0410/_data",
    "Destination": "/data/configdb",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Mode": "rw",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": ""
  }
]
```

### Set it manually

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes) `source` and `target` of volumes can be specified manually.

```
volumes:
  - type: bind
    source: ./volumes/mongodb
    target: /data/db
```

hopefully resulting in

```json
{
  "Type": "bind",
  "Source": "/home/username/app/backend/volumes/mongodb",
  "Destination": "/data/db",
  "Mode": "",
  "RW": true,
  "Propagation": "rprivate"
}
```

Comment: and what if the mount section yet empty (`Mounts: []`)?

Comment: Then this means nothing has been mounted.

Comment: I have a volume defined for a service in `docker-compose.yml`. When I run the inspect command the mount looks correct but there are no files in it. I'm using relative file paths as it has to work locally and in CI.

Answer (score 1):

It's very strange. I tried to check this issue with my `docker 1.6.0` so I created an image similair to yours:

```
FROM ubuntu:utopic
WORKDIR /var/dynamo
EXPOSE 8001
```

Then I mounted the `$(pwd)` to the container and I was able to exchange files between host filesystem and container:

```
➜  ololo  echo $(pwd)                                                                       
/tmp/ololo
➜  ololo  ls         
Dockerfile  kikiboi
➜  ololo  docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/var/dynamo volume_issue bash
root@9b15875997ba:/var/dynamo# ls
Dockerfile  kikiboi
root@9b15875997ba:/var/dynamo# touch container_file
root@9b15875997ba:/var/dynamo# exit
➜  ololo  ls
container_file  Dockerfile  kikiboi
```

Also you need to ensure that `/Users/dave/Sites/davesrepo/dynamo` on your host and `/var/dynamo` inside your container have the same `inode` number. Use `stat` utility fot this:

```
➜  ~  stat -c %i /tmp/ololo
1835031
➜  ~  docker run --rm -it -v /tmp/ololo:/var/dynamo ubuntu:utopic stat -c %i /var/dynamo
1835031
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the stat utility is and how to find the inode?

Comment: Perhaps this is an issue with newer versions of Docker. I'm on version 1.9.1

Comment: In your example you are creating a file in docker to share with the host. I'm not trying to share files from docker to the host.... it's the other way around, from the host to docker. To see changes as I am developing.

Comment: @digitaldavenyc I'm doing the same thing: you can see that files from ```/tmp/ololo``` (host) still exist in ```/var/dynamo``` folder (container). Probably you really need to downgrade ```docker```. We use ```1.6``` and ```1.7``` with ```Centos 6```. Everything  is OK

Comment: @digitaldavenyc I have added ```stat``` use case

Comment: Downgrading docker to 1.6.0 fixed the issue! Glad it's fixed, very frustrated with docker that downgrading fixed something as critical as mounting volumes. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @digitaldavenyc would you be able to open an issue on GitHub? Mounting of host-directories (permits they are inside `/Users` for boot2docker) should not have changed since docker 1.6, and we haven't had reports for this, so I'm interested to have this looked into. Could be something in your setup. I don't think downgrading to an old version should be the solution.

Comment: @thaJeztah Sure I commented on a separate thread but I'll open up a new issue.

Answer (score 1):

my situation was win10 WSL ubuntu. I had docker-compose and docker engine installed on ubuntu, docker desktop on windows.
It turns out the `docker run -v $(pwd):<containerPathName>` command has to be in the windows.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it appeared that my WSL didn't see anything on the drive (D) where my mounted folder was located. But other drives (C, E, G) were visible just fine. This was resulting for Docker not see anything.

TLDR: this is what helped me

1. In PowerShell run `wsl`
2. Run `mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/host/d`. Where `D:` is your Windows drive and `/mnt/host/d` the path where the contents of the `D:` will be accessible. `/mnt/host/d` must be similar to your other drives locations to know this you can run `df -h` command.

[image]

End.

From now your drive and all it contents must be visible by wsl as well as by Docker when you mount you directory.

But I can't tell why this drive wasn't mounted originally. I use fresh Windows 11 and installed wsl during Docker installation.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to include something like this in `Dockerfile`, the important is the `VOLUME` to specify the [mountable directories](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes) in the container then only `-v $(pwd):/var/dynamo` will be valid

```
RUN mkdir -p /var/dynamo
VOLUME /var/dynamo
WORKDIR /var/dynamo
```

Comment: This won't work when your using virtualbox verson of docker machine. Virtualbox can't load files this way and therefore neither can docker machine.

Comment: @digitaldavenyc you didn't mention anything about Virtualbox in the question!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which took almost 2 days to fix. My docker compose file had 2 services integrated. The second service able to get the CSV file from the source code the defined volume. But the first service could not. I defined the container/path correctly for both volumes.

I tried with changing the host/path but the issue persisted. At last I just changed the container/path to /var/opt which is the standard Linux directory. And the issue resolved. In fact the WORKDIR of the Dockerfile of this service is not /var/opt but /workplace. But when using /workplace in the docker-compose.yml, it was not able to get the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have run into a similar problem running from a the command line then as mentioned above use the full path name from root on a linux based machine.

`docker run --entrypoint bash -v /Users/<username>/cool_tech_stuff/data:/data -it ubuntu`

Answer (score -3):

I use 1.9 and this works fine:

```
Docker run  -d -t --restart=on-failure:3 -h docker_console -p 8880:80 -v ~/docker_console/var/www:/var/www --name docker_console repo/docker_console
```

It connects `~/docker_console/var/www` on the host to `/var/www` in the container.
What if you use a directory name and not a variable?

Comment: Read the accepted response, the issue was mounting outside the user directory on the host.

Comment: Your also not reading the issue properly or the accepted response, the issue was that the mounted volume for VirtualBox was moved outside of the user directory, which VirtualBox can't do.