# Docker mounts and empty volume

Tags: docker

I am running docker on ubuntu server 16.04 and I am running a container trying to mount a volume with my let's encrypt certificates..

I am doing:

```
docker run  ....  -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite:/certs ....
```

on mysite folder I have my .pem files, but inside my container i find the folder certs created but it is empty!! I don't know why it is not mounting the files that are inside mysite folder...

Initially mysite folder had belongs to root but I change ownership to the current user with 'chown'.. I am also running docker run with 'sudo' but it is still not coping my folder.

I have no idea what to do :(

Comment: Try to move your certs to another opened folder and mount it inside (`-v` flag)... It still can be permission issues

Comment: I tried to copy the entire folder without success.. then I tried to copy file by file into another folder and this time I find my files inside my container :) ! Is there another way or I will always have to move my .pem files away from there??

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504156/docker-volume-not-mounting-any-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the mount flag.

```
docker run -it \
--mount src=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite,target=/certs,type=bind ubuntu
```

Or move your certs to a named volume.

[image]

You'll have to move your certs into that directory given under "Mountpoint"

[Volumes docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/)

[Bind Mount docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/)

Comment: I will try this and I will make you know! Thank you :)

Comment: I am like 99% sure this should solve the issue for you.

Comment: I used the bind thing :)