# Serve simple static website via Docker and NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx

I would like to run NGINX in Docker and serve some files, but I am not able to do it this way:

```
docker run --rm --name some-nginx -p 10088:80 -v mydir:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro nginx
```

I am able to see http://localhost:10088 but if I try to access any file in `mydir/`, it fails. For example http://localhost:10088/README.md gives this result:

```
2020/01/21 07:10:20 [error] 6#6: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/README.md" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /README.md HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:10088"
172.17.0.1 - - [21/Jan/2020:07:10:20 +0000] "GET /README.md HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0" "-"
```

Any idea how to setup nginx easily?

Note: I don't want to create new image as suggested at https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx, I want to use volume.

Note 2: I've just noticed (after attach to the nginx container):

```
root@a2813aa84991:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls
50x.html  index.html
```

It seems volume `mydir/` is not mounted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Volume not mounting any files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504156/docker-volume-not-mounting-any-files)

Comment: @emix Not really, but the problem is similar: I need to use absolute path instead of relative.

Comment: Since you have mounted your container using `name:/path` syntax, Docker created a volume for you, named `mydir`. You can verify that using `docker volume ls`

Answer (score 0):

I have to **mount volume with absolute path**:

```
docker run --rm --name some-nginx -p 10088:80 -v $(pwd)/repository:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro nginx
```

This works.