# Docker | access host file in python within docker container

Tags: python, docker, ssl, certbot

I am trying to access certbot ssl certificates on my host machine within a docker container.
My certifications are located in /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com
I am loading my container using the args:

`docker run -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com:/certs -it --rm -p 80:80 kaws/kaws_app:latest`

My python script within the docker container says that the files or directories are not found.
I'm trying to load the certificates that exist in /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/

The error I'm receiving says:

```
ssl_context.load_cert_chain('/certs/fullchain.pem', '/certs/privkey.pem')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How do I access files on my host machine from my python script within my docker container?

Dockerfile

```
# Use the official Python 3 image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3-alpine

RUN \
  apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip \
  && apk upgrade --update \
  && apk add git \
  && apk add --update alpine-sdk \
  && apk add libffi-dev openssl-dev \
  && apk --no-cache --update add build-base

COPY . /app

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
  gcc musl-dev

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Cleanup dev dependencies
RUN apk del -f .build-deps

RUN chmod 444 app.py
RUN chmod 444 requirements.txt

# Service must listen to $PORT environment variable.
# This default value facilitates local development.
ENV PORT 80
ENV PORT 443

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

Update:
I ran the following code within my python script to see if it could see the certs and its able to see them, but it still gives an error.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/certs"):
    for filename in files:
        print(filename)
```

Output:

```
docker run kaws/kaws_app:latest
chain.pem
fullchain.pem
privkey.pem
cert.pem
README
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/app_pusher.py", line 83, in <module>
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain('/certs/fullchain.pem', '/certs/privkey.pem')
```

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: Are you sure `/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem` and `/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem` exist?

Comment: @jtlz2 I'm running ubuntu 20.04.
I'm sure the files exist, I can cat/print them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mount a host directory in a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504156/docker-volume-not-mounting-any-files

Comment: Does the python process have the required permissions to list those files in that dir?

Comment: @jtlz2 I'll try adding permissions to the files in the directory and try again.  Thank you for your time

Comment: @jtlz2 I was mistaken, the permissions even at 777 can't see the files for some reason.  when I use `ls /certs` in run, it shows the files though, but the python script says `ssl_context.load_cert_chain('/certs/fullchain.pem', '/certs/privkey.pem')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag, you need to drop the `:` after `/certs`.

Your command is then

`docker run -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com:/certs -it --rm -p 80:80 kaws/kaws_app:latest`

You may need to enable sharing on your OS as well (you do on macOS).

Comment: sorry, that was a typo.  i'm on ubunut 20.04

Comment: can you share dockerfile ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan edited and added dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

You should mount cert dictionary into docker container:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com:/certs -p 80:80 kaws/kaws_app:latest
```

Comment: Isn't the third argument to `-v` for read/write etc.?

Comment: isn't this what i'm doing?