# docker-compose up not mounting volumes in the host directory

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I have Ubuntu 20.04 machine and my docker version is 20.10.08. Following is my docker-compose file:

```
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.7
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "kafka-vol:/bitnami/kafka/config"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - "kafka-vol:/bitnami/kafka/config"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
volumes:
  kafka-vol:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /home/ned/advice/data/conf/kafka
```

I am using `docker-compose` for running the containers. It is running fine with no errors but my configs of kafka are not mounting in the host directory. So far I have tried the following:

1. Allowed the permission 1001 on the folder as mentioned in the bitnami docker image documentation.
2. Gave relative path `.advice/data/conf/kafka` in the volumes
3. Gave full path direct in the volumes of the services as (without the double quotes as suggested in [Docker Volume not mounting any files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504156/docker-volume-not-mounting-any-files)):

```
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - advice/data/conf/kafka:/bitnami/kafka/config
```

When I do `docker volume inspect kafka-vol`. It gave me the following output:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2022-01-28T07:16:22Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "ned",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.2.3",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "kafka-vol"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/ned_kafka-vol/_data",
        "Name": "ned_kafka-vol",
        "Options": {
            "device": "/home/ned/advice/data/conf/kafka",
            "o": "bind",
            "type": "none"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Now, I don't know what am I doing wrong that it isn't mounting my config files. The directory `/home/ned/advice/data/conf/kafka` is empty. I was expecting docker's kafka config at this `/home/ned/advice/data/conf/kafka` directory

Comment: is bitnami folder in your current directory ? If so, try =>
`kafka-vol:./bitnami/kafka/config` (just added a dot)
& I also hope you have not used inverted commas (") in volume binding

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The server properties are generated from templates internal to the containers. Is there a specific reason you're trying to set hard coded configs? Mounting a volume will override the container path, not copy data that's at that path out of the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this directory in this container is meant to mount external config files, it's completely empty. It's also called `KAFKA_MOUNTED_CONF_DIR` in their [env script](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/blob/master/3/debian-10/rootfs/opt/bitnami/scripts/kafka-env.sh#L69-L71).

So If you want to mount your own config, them probably like this.

```sh
mkdir config
echo foobar > config/config.txt
chown -R 1001:1001 config
```

```yaml
  kafka:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - "./config:/bitnami/kafka/config"
```

```sh
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker exec -ti test_kafka_1 ls /bitnami/kafka/config
config.txt
```

As @OneCricketeer found out, if you want to get the default config it's using, you need to get that from `/opt/bitnami/kafka/config`.

If you want to mount the Kafka default configs to the host system, you need to use that path.

```yaml
version: "2"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.7
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "zookeeper_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - "kafka_data:/bitnami"
      # the volume should be mounted to this path
      - "kafa_configs:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local
  # this is your volume
  kafa_configs:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: ./config
```

```sh
$ mkidr config
$ sudo chown 1001:1001 config
$ docker compose up -d
ls -ltrh config/
total 76K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 1.2K Jan 24 23:14 zookeeper.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 1.2K Jan 24 23:14 trogdor.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 1.1K Jan 24 23:14 tools-log4j.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 4.6K Jan 24 23:14 log4j.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 2.3K Jan 24 23:14 connect-standalone.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 2.5K Jan 24 23:14 connect-mirror-maker.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 2.1K Jan 24 23:14 connect-log4j.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  881 Jan 24 23:14 connect-file-source.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  883 Jan 24 23:14 connect-file-sink.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 5.4K Jan 24 23:14 connect-distributed.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  909 Jan 24 23:14 connect-console-source.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  906 Jan 24 23:14 connect-console-sink.properties
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jan 29 17:05 kraft
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 6.9K Jan 29 17:05 server.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 1.9K Jan 29 17:05 producer.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 1.3K Jan 29 17:05 consumer.properties
```

Depending on why you are doing this, maybe a [cp command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) would suffice.

Comment: While this works, it seems OP wants the container to create files in the host, not other way around

Comment: @OneCricketeer, in this directory, are no files when the container starts, I have checked that. So logically, nothing will be written to the host. I assume they end up in `/bitnami/kafka/data` Documentation is suggesting to mount the full `/bitnami/kafka`, if you want to persist data.  Maybe they will come eventually through zooker, I dont know kafka enough. OP should first check if in a basic setup some content will be eventually in this directory or not. If they can show that this is the case, then we could further trouble shoot. In setup from the docs, it's not happening.

Comment: I hav tried with the compose from the docs https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka#run-the-application-using-docker-compose.

Comment: First my answer was kind of saying what your comment said, you can see it in the edit history. But then I thought, I probably misunderstand OP. Usually we want to mount config file and not get them out of the container.

Comment: From what I understood, OP wants to either put files into these paths, or have the container copy the properties file out to the host https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/blob/master/3/debian-10/rootfs/opt/bitnami/scripts/kafka-env.sh#L69-L71

Comment: @OneCricketeer, as I said. If you do an `exec ls` on this path, you will see that there is nothing inside. Not a single file.

Comment: Maybe because the config files are at `/opt/bitnami/kafka/config`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I think you are right. Looking at the link you have posted, the file must be there.

Comment: Yes the whole path from ```/opt/bitnami/kafka/config``` solved the issue.