# How to setup frontail with Django and Docker

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, logging

I am trying to setup [Frontail](https://github.com/mthenw/frontail) to access the logs for a Django application deployed using Docker locally. Has anyone done this before? There is very little documentation or other information online.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by adding Frontail as another service to the docker-compose.yml file. After pulling the Frontail [image from Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/mthenw/frontail/) Under your other services, you can add:

```
services:
...
  logs:
    image: mthenw/frontail
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
    command: /var/log/log_filename.log
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: path_to_logs_directory
        target: /var/log
```

Where log_filename.log is the filename your Django logger is using and path_to_logs_directory is the relative directory of this file. The command argument is what is passed to Frontail (i.e. the logs file to monitor). Note that there is no real reason I used the `/var/log` directory in the Frontail image - it just seemed to make sense after looking around the file structure.

The only way I could get this to work was with a bind mount [thanks to nonNumericalFloat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66868431/14334937) but I'd be interested to know if there is a better way to do this.